# Dustjs with webpack don't load all files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, dust.js

Good Morning,

I'm using `dustjs-linekedin 2.7.2.`, with Webpack and Angular to validate template in brownser.

I need load all file in `dustjs-linkedin/lib/` or just to load `dust-full.js`in directory `dustjs-linkedin/dist`

I have declared look like this `window.dust = require('dustjs-linkedin')`, it works, but just load the dust.js, like image below.

[sucess load just /lib/dust.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hif6.png)

When I try to use `dust.compile(..)`I'm getting a error, `dust.compile`is not a function.

Just to be clear what I wish, would be to use:

```
  function checkDustTemplate (template) {
     try {
      debugger
       var compiled = dust.compile(data);
       var tmpl = dust.loadSource(compiled);

       dust.render(tmpl, { name: "Name" }, function(err, out) {
       document.getElementById('output').textContent = out;
     }
     catch(err) {
       console.log(err);
   }}
```

I have tried load just `dust-full.js`because that have all I need:

- `window.dust = require('dustjs-linkedin/dist/dust-full.js')`

But I getting this error below:

[error don't load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfZrf.png)

I'm sorry for English and for something that is wrong in question.

Comment: Try to `require('dustjs-linkedin/index.js')`

Comment: My friend, I forgot to mention, had tried that too
 I getting this error:
`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'dust.core' in /node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib
 @ ./~/dustjs-linkedin/lib/parser.js 4:4-6:6`

Comment: And it also happens that `ERROR in ./~/dustjs-linkedin/lib/compiler.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'dust.core' in /node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib
 @ ./~/dustjs-linkedin/lib/compiler.js 3:4-5:6`

Comment: You're hitting an interesting combination of issues that we haven't really foreseen. I think your best bets are either to include the built dust using something like `ProvidePlugin`, or maybe try `let dust = require('dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust'); let compiler = require('dustjs-linkedin/lib/compiler');`

Comment: @interrobang same issue https://gist.github.com/valimkings/641dc3048ae93ec5a00867d9d157b650

Comment: Did you managed to resolve that ? I have exactly the same issue with webpack and this version of dustjs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that webpack supports AMD but not named AMD modules. Dustjs provides alternatives to AMD in its loading so you can disable AMD for these modules with the `imports-loader`.

Install `imports-loader` with `npm install --save imports-loader`. Then add this rule to the `module.rules` section of your webpack.config.js:

```
{
  test: /dustjs-linkedin/,
  loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false',
}
```

Then you can import dust and compile:

```
import dust from 'dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust';
import 'dustjs-linkedin/lib/compiler';
```